# Como posso tabular um arquivo em massa?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Olá, tenho um arquivo de 64500 linhas e 11 colunas para tabular. O arquivo original veio do sistema do contador, que é um sistema para impressão de papel. Já consegui tirar os cabeçalhos, porém estou tendo problemas com a tabulação. Alguém conhece uma ferramenta ou método que reconheça quando a linha está correta e quando não está?

[image: exemplo]

Quando não estiver preciso excluir duas tabulações e ela volta para o normal. Este erro acontece 7122 vezes no meu arquivo. O arquivo possui 1050 páginas para impressão e eu preciso também remover 6 linhas a cada página. Alguém pode me ajudar? Pensei em substituir a tabulação por vírgulas para criar um CSV mas não consegui.

Comment: É um trabalho para expressões regulares. Acho que dá para resolver sem precisar programar nenhum script, só usando o Notepad++. Estude regex e use a ferramenta de substituição de texto.

Comment: Favor [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104), um exemplo do que é considerado correto e não. O que seria excluir duas tabulações? Seriam as células? Linhas?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar este código para corrigir as tabulações:

```
Sub FixTabs()

Dim i, j, lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'Contagem total de linhas

j = 1
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Do While Range("C" & i).Value = "" 'Substitua "C" pela coluna correspondente C/P
        Range("C" & i, "D" & i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft '*Ajustar colunas a serem excluídas
        j = j + 1 'iterador para sair do loop
        If j = lastRow Then
            i = j
            GoTo continue 'pular linhas de código
        End If
    Loop
continue:
Next i
End Sub
```

*Use <kbd>F8</kbd> para executar passo a passo e verifique se o código elimina as células corretas